# Find the $A \cap B$ for given sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two non empty and defined sets 
$$A = \{(x,y) : y = e^x , x \in \mathbb{R} \},$$ $$B = \{(x,y) : y = x , x \in \mathbb{R} \}.$$

What is $A \cap B$ ?

How to write Set A and B in roster form ?

Roster form : In this method a set is described by listing elements, seperated by commas, within braces {}. The set of vowels of English Alphabet may be described as {a, e, i, o, u}.

How to express elements of sets with exponential function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off let's try to make sense of the intersection of $A,B$. Remember that
$$
A \cap B = \{ c \mid c \in A \land c \in B \}
$$
so we want to find
$$
\{ c \mid c \in \{ (x,y) \mid y = e^x, x \in \mathbb{R} \} \land c \in \{ (x,y) \mid y = x, x \in \mathbb{R} \} \}
$$
Now let's expand out $c = (w,z)$ so that we're finding
$$
\{ (w,z) \mid (w,z) \in \{ (x,y) \mid y = e^x, x \in \mathbb{R} \} \land (w,z) \in \{ (x,y) \mid y = x, x \in \mathbb{R} \} \}
$$
Now we need to figure out which elements $(w,z)$ are such that both $w = z$ and $w = e^z$ simultaneously (since this is the only way which $(w,z)$ can be in both $A$ and $B$). Now we can see if $w = z, w = e^z$ we have
$$
z = e^z
$$
do you know of a real number where this is true?

Another way of viewing this problem is noticing that $A$ is the graph of $y = e^x$ and $B$ is the graph of $y=x$. If you plot these two functions then the points where they intersect make up the intersection of $A,B$.

For representing $A,B$ in roster form, I am unsure. In my experience you can represent countable sets in roster form (meaning sets which you can enumerate) but both $A,B$ are uncountable.

Answer (score 3):

Do you agree that :

$A=\{(x,e^x) :x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $B=\{(x,x) :x\in \mathbb{R}\}$

Now how does an element in their intersection look like?

What does $(x,x)=(x,e^x)$ tells about $x$?

Comment: x belongs to set of real numbers

Comment: How to express elements of sets with exponential function ?  How to use the exponential function ?

Comment: when do you say two ordered pairs are equal?? when does $(a,b)=(c,d)$?

Comment: when a=c and b=d.                 Another case when set A = set B

Comment: so you are saying $(a,b)=(c,d)$ if $a=b$ and $c=d$.. that is fine... Now tell me when does $(x,x)=(x,e^x)$ (use same idea as you have done for $a,b,c,d$)

Comment: @ Praphulla Koushik Can u tell me how to write set B in roster form ? if i get set B in roster form it would be much easier to solve it its my thought

Comment: May be you should read what actually a roaster form is... what i have written is actually roaster form for  $B$

Comment: @ Praphulla Koushik i am correct i have verrified. a set is often described in the following two ways.

Comment: 1. Roster method or Listing Method :  In this method a set is described by listing elements, seperated by commas, within braces {}. The set of vowels of English Alphabet may be described as {a, e, i, o, u}.

Comment: roaster form is something where you do not use words to describe but you would just write elements... see that i have not described in words when i say $(x,e^x)$... take some more time to realize what was written...

Comment: 2. Set builder method or Rule method : in this method a set is described by a characterizing property  P(x) of its elementx. In such a case a set is described as {x:P(x)holds} or {x/ P(x) holds} which is red as 'the set of all x such that P(x) holds'. Example: A={1,2,3,4,5,6} can be written as {x: x < 7, x belongs to set of natural numbers}

Comment: According to your last question it means x=e^x

Comment: so, when does $x=e^x$